# ¿Cómo instalar electronjs en Ubuntu detrás de un proxy?

Tags: git, npm, github, electron

He intentado instalar electronjs en varias ocasiones pero no he podido, me encuentro detrás de un proxy y cada intento me ha devuelto el siguiente error

```
> electron@10.1.5 postinstall /home/dipper/Development/my-electron-app/node_modules/electron
> node install.js

RequestError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN github.com github.com:443
    at ClientRequest.request.once.error (/home/dipper/Development/my-electron-app/node_modules/got/source/request-as-event-emitter.js:178:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at ClientRequest.origin.emit.args (/home/dipper/Development/my-electron-app/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/source/index.js:37:11)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:401:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/dipper/Development/my-electron-app/package.json'
npm WARN my-electron-app No description
npm WARN my-electron-app No repository field.
npm WARN my-electron-app No README data
npm WARN my-electron-app No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron@10.1.5 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@10.1.5 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dipper/.npm/_logs/2020-11-10T17_15_33_463Z-debug.log
```

He intentado editar el archivo ~/.gitconfig con la siguiente configuración pero sigo recibiendo el mismo error, tengo además abierto el proxy del sistema operativo y nada.

```
[https]
        proxy = https://127.0.0.1:3128
[http]
        proxy = http://127.0.0.1:3128
```

Comment: `getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN` suele ser por un problema de DNS. ¿ La máquina resuelve los nombres ? ¿ Puedes hacer `ping www.google.es` ?

Comment: Pienso que sea problema con el DNS porque intente instalar con snap y también tuve problemas, lo mismo con pip3 de python, sin embargo, navego sin problemas por internet y aplicaciones que tengo con el vscode me permiten instalar plugins con acceso a internet sin problema. No sé como solucionar el error.